# Expanding upon express.js response module

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm writing an application where I need two templating languages.  Currently, I'm using code like

```
app.get('/route1', function(req, res) {
  res.render('path/to/jade/template' {title: "Express")
})

app.get('route2', function(req, res) {
  var _        = require('lodash')
    , fs       = require('fs')
    , template = fs.readFileSync('views/path/to/lodash/template')


  res.send ( _.template(template, {title: "Express"}) )
})
```

I'd really like to move that into another res function, like

```
res.template('path/to/lodash/template', { data })
```

While I can just edit the express node_module, that's hardly an elegant solution. Are there any examples of how to do this?  Does express.js give you the option to expand on what it already has?

---

#### Update:

I've looked into express's `app.engine` function and have the following code:

```
app.engine('js', function(path, options, fn) {
  var file = fs.readFileSync(path, 'utf-8')
    , template = require('lodash').template(file)
  console.log(template(options)) // this logs the file how I want
  return template(options)
})
```

While it's logging what I want, nothing seems to be returning to the client.  The request just hangs.  I've tried return statements such as `return function() { return template(options) }` and `return function(locals) { return template(locals) }`, however it doesn't seem to be calling that function, so I believe that syntax is for an older version of express

Also, I'm aware that `consolidate.js` solves this problem, but if possible I would prefer to solve it without it (or at least know how :)

Comment: How are you currently setting up `jade` to be called by `res.render`? Show your app configuration for that.

Comment: @loganfsmyth The default express configuration - `app.set('view engine', 'jade')`

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work after playing around some.  I'd love some comments on my solution :)

The working code is as follows:

```
app.engine('js', function(path, options, fn) {
  var file = require('fs').readFileSync(path, 'utf-8')
  var str  = require('lodash').template(file, options)
  fn(null, str)
})
```

I still need to add better (some) error handling, probably move the rendering into a `readFile` callback as opposed to `readFileSync`, maybe pull out the locals from the options param, but at the very least this works